# Get circle to orbit with given equations using Python graphics.py module

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, geometry, zelle-graphics

I was given this equation in order to get the circle to orbit. I created an infinite loop assuming it should orbit forever. `x = cx + r*cos(t)` and `y = cy + r*sin(t)`

Am I doing something wrong?

```
from graphics import *
import math
def main():
    win=GraphWin("Cirlce",600,600)
    x=250
    y=70
    c=Circle(Point(x,y),18)
    c.draw(win)
    v=True
    while v==True:
        c.undraw()
        x = x + c.getRadius()*math.cos(2)
        y = y + c.getRadius()*math.sin(2)
        c=Circle(Point(x,y),18)
        c.draw(win)
main()
```

Comment: I don't know, *are* you doing something wrong? What has made you think you are?

Comment: Nothing is showing up after I added the whileloop, sorry for not being more specific

Comment: its something wrong with the equation im not translating it into code correctly. I printed the values.

Comment: You say you used the equation `x = cx + r*cos(t)`, but I don't see any `t` in your program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
    x = x + c.getRadius()*math.cos(2)
    y = y + c.getRadius()*math.sin(2)
```

You are moving in a straight line. And, as your code runs quite fast, it probably goes out of scope quite quickly. The correct version would be:

```
x0, y0 = 0, 0 # Coordinates of the centre
r = 2         # Radius
t = 0
dt = 0.01     # Or anything that looks smooth enough.

while True:   # No need for an extra variable here
    c.undraw()    # I don't know this graphics library
                  # I will assume what you did is correct
    x = x0 + r * math.cos(t)
    y = y0 + r * math.sin(t)
    c=Circle(Point(x,y),18)
    c.draw(win)
    t += dt
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

At the end of the loop I send it to sleep for a bit so it goes at a finite pace. Some graphics libraries include a `rate` function, that allows you to run it at a fixed number of frames per second, independently of how fast the loop is in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

> c.undraw()  # I don't know this graphics library, I will assume what
>   you did is correct

Using `c.undraw()`, `c = Circle(...)`, and `c.draw()` on every loop iteration seems wasteful when GraphicsObjects can `move(dx, dy)`.  However, the tricky part is the movement is relative so you have to calculate the difference to your next position:

```
import math
import time
from graphics import *

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600, 600

win = GraphWin("Circle", WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
win.setCoords(-WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, -WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2, WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2)

ORBIT_RADIUS = 200
PLANET_RADIUS = 18
SOLAR_RADIUS = 48

x0, y0 = 0, 0  # Coordinates of the center

t = 0.0
dt = 0.01  # Or anything that looks smooth enough.
delay = 0.01

star = Circle(Point(x0, y0), SOLAR_RADIUS)
star.setFill("yellow")
star.draw(win)

orbit = Circle(Point(x0, y0), ORBIT_RADIUS)
orbit.setOutline("lightgray")
orbit.draw(win)

planet = Circle(Point(x0 + ORBIT_RADIUS * math.cos(t), y0 + ORBIT_RADIUS * math.sin(t)), PLANET_RADIUS)
planet.setFill("blue")
planet.draw(win)

while True:
    x, y = x0 + ORBIT_RADIUS * math.cos(t), y0 + ORBIT_RADIUS * math.sin(t)
    center = planet.getCenter()
    planet.move(x - center.getX(), y - center.getY())

    t = (t + dt) % (2 * math.pi)

    if win.checkMouse() is not None:
        break

    time.sleep(delay)

win.close()
```

I added a star as it's hard to appreciate that something is orbiting without seeing what's being orbited:

[image]

You can click on the window to exit cleanly.